# How to remotely debug java app and forwarding the port to virtual machine?

Tags: java, debugging, vagrant, remote-debugging, portforwarding

I want to start a java application in a host machine (windows 7) with debugging enabled

```
-Xdebug 
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Then I want to start a virtual machine through vagrant and forward the port `5005` to the guest machine.

On the guest machine I want to connect to port `5005` and debug the app.

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5005, host: 5005, protocol: 'tcp'
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5005, host: 5005, protocol: 'udp'
```

The problem is that once the virtual machine is running the java app crashes immediately when I start it. When I change the debug port to something else than `5005` the app starts.

Comment: Are you forwarding incoming traffic in port 5005 on the same machine where the java program is running? That is wrong, the java program needs to be able to listen to that port.

Comment: I am forwarding from host's `5005` to guests `5005` - but I just realized that I need to forward from guest's `5005` to host's `5005`

Comment: Even that should not be necessary. If your forward from guest:5005 to host:5005 then you can debug on guest on localhost:5005, with the tunnel doing the forwarding. But it would be better then to debug on guest on host:5005 itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes I just use the vm's gateway address as host and the java app's debugging port. The debugger connects now but does not break on a breakpoint.

Comment: That is different question but it is most likely because the source (guest) and target (host) are not in sync. Try a method entry breakpoint instead of a line breakpoint. I am converting my comments to reply in case you want to accept it as correct answer.

Comment: method entry breakpoint is hit and after that line breakpoint within that method works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you should not forward port on the machine where the the JVM is running, it is the Java App that needs to receive traffic on that port and startup fails most likely because the port has already been forwarded.

Forwarding on the other end is not necessary either, you can just debug on <target>:<port> instead.